# Bootstrap 3 modal disappears on iPad Safari only after choosing option from select menu

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari, bootstrap-modal

I have a registration function in a web application that takes a user through a four-step process to add information to the site.  When a user clicks the 'Add' button, a Bootstrap modal appears and the user starts on step #1.

Each step has a menu of options for a user to choose from and the data that is populated in each step is dependent on the previous steps' choices.  A user can leave a step blank and continue, but then they have no choices to make for the rest of the process.  This functionality is behaving as expected in every desktop and mobile browser except for Safari on iPad.

In Safari, the user will open the modal, choose data in step 1, and move to step 2.  If the user does not choose anything in this dropdown they can continue to step 3.  However, if they do make a choice in step 2, the modal disappears and the user cannot continue.  This only happens in Safari for iPad/iPhone.

I have tried setting up the web inspector on the iPad and loading the console on a Mac, but there are no errors or other messages of use in the console.  I'm trying to figure out if this is a bug in Safari, or if Safari handles modal inputs from a select tag differently than other browsers.

Comment: having a similar problem, bootstrap's modal disappears on iPad Air after any elements inside this modal is clicked

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14975

Answer (score 0):

Had a developer friend take a look.  He added this function:

```
jQuery.usingSafari = function(allowDevices){
allowDevices = allowDevices != undefined ?  allowDevices : true;
if(!allowDevices){
    return /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent)  
        && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1 
        && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') == -1
        && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') == -1 
        && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') == -1;
} else{
    var results =  /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent) &&    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1;
    return results;
}
```

}

```
//Disable backdrop
if(jQuery.usingSafari(false)) {
document.write('<style>div.modal-backdrop{ display:none; }</style>');
```

}

And then the modal call:

```
    jQuery('#player-lightbox').modal({
            backdrop: jQuery.usingSafari(true) ? "static" : true,
            show:true}
        );
```

This seems to have fixed the problem.  Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by the `fade` transition. I first detected if the app runs on iOS, then made a query for `.modal` elements and removed class `fade`. This resolved the issue both on iPad/iPhone. Note: Modal backdrop might need some extra effort to make that play nice with the virtual keyboard popping in and out.

To illustrate:

```
if(isIOS())
  $('.modal').removeClass('fade');
```

Edit: iPad (horizontal) also required

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $(this).find('.modal-backdrop').css('position', 'absolute');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a droplist inside a container that was disappearing upon making a selection and this was ONLY happening on a actual IPAD device (checking in chrome w/ the device toolbar with 'IPAD' selected worked fine). This seems to be a known bug as mentioned in the comment above.

Changing the css for the container to **position: absolute** resolved the issue for me. However it would break the layout for other devices & viewports.

The fix was to target only IPADs with the modified css rule:

```
@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  .your-container {
    position: absolute;
  }  
}
@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  .your-container {
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```